# Will invoking two methods on @Stateless use the same instance?

Tags: ejb-3.0

If I have something like this-

```
@Stateless
public class EJBServcie{

         public void method1(){
            // some code goes here
         }
         public void method2(){
            // some code goes here
         }
}
```

with the bean using it as-

```
public class Bean{

   @EJB
   EJBService ejbService;

   punlic void action(){

     ejbService.method1();
     ejbService.method2();
   }

}
```

In this example, method1 is invoked on an instance of EJBService.  Will method2 be invoked on the same instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EJB container might choose to use the same instance depending on pooling configuration or concurrent calls, but there is no guarantee: it could choose to use a different instance for each call.